# Prove that the k-fold cross validation error is an almost unbiased estimate of the risk

Tags: expected-value, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

In the setting of linear regression:

The prediction error using k-fold cross-validation is given by :
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\begin{split}
err_{k-fold} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n/k}\sum_{j\in ind[i]}l(h_{D_{(-i)}}(x_j),y_j)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Where $h_{D_{(-i)}}$ means that the model has been trained on all the fold except the ith one

I want to show that :

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\begin{split}
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{D\sim p}\left[ err_{k-fold}\right] = 
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{{D'\sim p} |{(x,y)\sim}p}\left[ (y-h_{D'}(x))^2.  \right] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Where  $D$ is a dataset of size n and  $D'$ is a dataset of size $n-\frac{n}{k}$

And then prove that the $err_{k-fold}$ is an almost unbiased estimate of the risk of $h_D$

---

My approach was to try to compute the expectation of $err_{k-fold}$ and use the fact that D and D' are sampled from the same distribution. but I am lost.
Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By linearity of expectation, you can push the expectation into the sum
$$E[\text{err}_k] = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{n/k} \sum_{j \in \text{fold}_i} 
 E[l(h_{D_{-i}}(x_j), y_j)].$$
The value of the inner expectation is precisely equal to $$\underset{\substack{D' \sim p \\ (x,y) \sim p}}{E}[l(h_{D'}(x), y)]$$
regardless of the value of $i$ and $j$. So the double sum is just an average of $n$ copies of the same quantity.

Comment: but on one side we have $D'$ and on the other side $D$. what rule states that since the datasets are drawn from the same distribution the average is the same?

Comment: @lalaland The expectation on the right-hand side still has $D \sim p$. But the hypothesis is trained on $D_{-i}$ which consists of $n-(n/k)$ independent draws and has the same distribution as $D'$.